# iOs - Parse - Handle many push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

I have a iPhone app using **Swift 2** and **Parse** as a back-end. In my app people can like everybody else pictures (the same way you will do it in Instagram). **The notification system works well** and everytime someone like a picture, I'm sending a Parse notification to the picture owner like this :

```
    let pushQuery:PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()
    pushQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: receiver)
    let push:PFPush = PFPush()
    let data = [
        "alert" : message,
        "badge" : "Increment",
        "sound" : "default"
    ]
    push.setData(data)
    push.setQuery(pushQuery)
    push.sendPushInBackground()
```

I'm facing a problem when I have a lot of users liking a picture in a short amount of time. The problem is that the receiver is flooded by Notifications and **I don't want the receiver to have his phone vibrating (or ringing) 100 times in 5 minutes**.

As I'm a new user using parse I have no idea if I have to modify some parameters in the server (Parse) of I have to do it programmatically (and I have no idea how to do this).

Anyone has an idea ? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution. create an extra column in your parse table called lastPush. In this store the date and time of the last push. So when you send a push first check to see if there is a lastPush value, if not send one and store the time. If there is a date then check if it's in your range, you can decide if you want to send a push or not. If you do remember to save the new time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Kex ! It's a great idea but is there any other possible solution "already implemented" ?